# TSQL + XML Nodes Query & XMLNameSpaces - Getting a list of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, xml-namespaces

I've been looking at the examples here but I'm still struggling to query my XML properly. 
I've been trying to break down my XML via SQL xml.nodes query but I don't get any results

This is the XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope 
    xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" 
    xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
    <gesmes:subject>Reference rates
    </gesmes:subject>
    <gesmes:Sender>
        <gesmes:name>European Central Bank
        </gesmes:name>
    </gesmes:Sender>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2013-12-09">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.3722"/>    
            <Cube currency="EUR" rate="1.0"/>
            </Cube>
        <Cube time="2013-12-10">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.5555"/>
            <Cube currency="EUR" rate="1.2"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>
```

I need to insert these values into a table in the following format:

```
MyDate      Currency    Rate
2013-12-09  USD         1.3722
2013-12-09  EUR         1.0
2013-12-10  USD         1.5555
2013-12-10  EUR         1.2
```

After a lot of attempts, I thought I'd try removing the gesmes* nodes and just replace it with  and I actually managed to get the values.

Here's my SQL which worked with :

```
    declare @xml as xml;
    set @xml = 
    '<Root>
    <Cube>
        <Cube time="2013-12-09">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.3722"/>
            <Cube currency="EUR" rate="1.0"/>
            </Cube>
        <Cube time="2013-12-10">
            <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.5555"/>
            <Cube currency="EUR" rate="1.2"/>
        </Cube>
    </Cube>
    </Root>'

    SELECT FXDate.value('@time', 'varchar(100)') AS FXDATE
        ,FXRates.value('@currency','varchar(100)') AS FXCurrency
        ,FXRates.value('@rate','varchar(100)') AS FXRate
    FROM @XML.nodes('Root/Cube/Cube') as Test(FXDate) 
    CROSS APPLY Test.FXDate.nodes('Cube') as Test2(FXRates);
```

I then realised it may have something to do with the namespaces(?) as I'd noticed someone else pointed this out for someone else' query.  So now I am rather stuck on how to get the SQL to work with namespaces.  As this file will be sent in as a parameter, I have to work with the name spaces.

This is my attempt at the SQL with the namespace except I get nothing in the results.  Any feedback/answers would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

```
declare @xml as xml;
set @xml = 
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gesmes:Envelope 
    xmlns:gesmes="http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01" 
    xmlns="http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref">
<gesmes:subject>Reference rates</gesmes:subject>
<gesmes:Sender>
    <gesmes:name>European Central Bank</gesmes:name>
</gesmes:Sender>
<Cube>
    <Cube time="2013-12-09">
        <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.3722"/>
        <Cube currency="EUR" rate="1.0"/>
        </Cube>
    <Cube time="2013-12-10">
        <Cube currency="USD" rate="1.5555"/>
        <Cube currency="EUR" rate="1.2"/>
    </Cube>
</Cube>
</gesmes:Envelope>'

select @xml

;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref' AS ns
,'http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01' as ns2 )
SELECT FXDate.value('@time', 'varchar(100)')
FROM @XML.nodes('ns:gesmes/Cube/Cube/Cube') as Test(FXDate)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.ecb.int/vocabulary/2002-08-01/eurofxref',
    'http://www.gesmes.org/xml/2002-08-01' AS ns)
SELECT 
    FXDate = FXDate.value('../@time', 'varchar(100)'),
    FXCurrency = FXDate.value('@currency','varchar(100)'),
    FXRate = FXDate.value('@rate','varchar(100)') 
FROM 
    @XML.nodes('ns:Envelope/Cube/Cube/Cube') as Test(FXDate)
```

Basically, the **default** XML namespace in your XML should be used as the default XML namespace in your query as well, and the second XML namespace just is listed with some prefix of your choice.

Also, your XPath was wrong in using `/Root` at the top - the root element is called `<Envelope>` in your XML here.

I also removed the `CROSS APPLY` since it doesn't seem to be necessary - just select the lowest level `<Cube>` entry and then use `../@time` to reference the "one-level up" attribute on the "parent" `<Cube>` XML element.